# Wrapper objects and equality

Tags: java

Why is it the case that if I run the .equals method on two wrapper objects it will return true as per the WrapperEqualsEquals Class below **but** (and I stress the but) why do we need to override the equals method in the Blob Class below in order for it to return true. Basically why do the wrapper objects get away with having to do an override of the .equals method?

```
    class WrapperEqualsEquals
    {
       public static void main(String []args)
       {
         Integer one=new Integer(1);
         Integer oneB=new Integer(1);

         System.out.println(one == oneB);
         System.out.println(one.equals(oneB));

       }
```

## }

```
    class OverrideEquals
    {
      public static void main (String [] args)
      {
        Blob a= new Blob(1,"a");
        Blob b= new Blob(1,"a");



        System.out.println(a==b);
        System.out.println(a.equals(b));

       }
```

## }

```
    class Blob
    {
      int blobNumber;
      String blobText;

      Blob(int blobNumber,String blobText)
      {
       this.blobNumber=blobNumber;
       this.blobText=blobText;
      }

          //"overriding" the 'equals' method

          public boolean equals (Object o)
      {

            if (o instanceof Blob)
    {
        Blob o2=(Blob)o;
        return ((o2.blobNumber==this.blobNumber) &&(o2.blobText==this.blobText))?
                    true:false;
    }

            else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: ? Both `Blob` and `Integer` override `Object.equals`. (`@Override` is a good idea. You've used `==` on `String`s. No need for `?true:false`.)

Answer (score 0):

By default, Object#equals(Object) returns true only if the hashcodes of the implicit and explicit parameters are equal.  Because you create two separate Blob objects, they wouldn't point to the same reference (as per hashCode()), therefore making them unequal *unless* the .equals method is overriden.  However, by Java convention, .equals should only return true if the two objects' hashcodes are equal, so you may wish to override hashCode as well.  This will also preserve memory usage.

Comment: `hashCode` isn't relevant to the question at hand. That's important for hash structures. Implementation of `Object.equals` does not use `hashCode`.